# How to blacklist a problem Wi-Fi access point by MAC address in Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, wireless-networking, mac-address, airport, wireless-access-point

So I am a small Mac-user cog in a larger Windows-based network machine.  The network here works fine for most everyone else (on PCs), but I have random timeouts and issues with the Wi-Fi.

Luckily, I have identified a few problem access points by MAC address (via their log messages in Console.app).

Is it possible to tell my AirPort on my Macbook to avoid those access points, and only speak with the access points who are far less touchy about me drinking the Apple kool-aid?

All of the points are on the same network SSID.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer to [Listing and choosing WLAN access points (base stations) in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/a/179832), there is no way to blacklist individual BSSIDs (i.e., base stations/access points).