# Blacklist a single access point of a wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking

At my university, one of the wireless access points is failing. When something tries to associate to the network using that access point, it deassociates the client, claiming 802.1X authentication failure. Other access points do work normally using the same credentials.

The issue has been reported, but after a month it still has still not been fixed. Now, I'm looking for a way to blacklist the access point's BSSID, so the OS prefers other access points on the same SSID.

How can I blacklist specific BSSIDs in either Mac OS X Snow Leopard or Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Listing and choosing WLAN access points (base stations) in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/167242/listing-and-choosing-wlan-access-points-base-stations-in-mac-os-x), OS X doesn't allow you to blacklist individual BSSID's.

Comment: That's too bad. Fortunately for me, the issue has been fixed, but it would have been nice if there was a workaround if it happened again. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can checkout this answer (haven't tested it yet myself): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363301/31489